# Imaginary asymptotics for the digamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

I often see asymptotics and precise expansion for the gamma $\Gamma$  or the digamma $\psi$ function $\psi$ when the argument goes to $+\infty$, in particular when it stays *real* (or in a given angle sector towards $+\infty$).

I would like to know the precise asymptotics along the *imaginary* axis, i.e. asymptotics for
$$\psi(x_0 + iy) = \frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(x_0 + iy)$$

when $x_0$ is fixed, say positive, and $y$ goes to $\pm \infty$. Do we know such an expansion, with explicit dependencies in $x_0$?

Typically, the Stirling formula
$$\Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}} \left(\frac{z}{e} \right)^z$$

is valid for all complex number in the angle sector $|\mathrm{arg}(z) - \pi| \geq \delta$ for any $\delta > 0$. This is unfortunately not enough to obtain information on the derivative $\Gamma'$, and therefore on $\psi$. Is there a similar formula for the digamma function?

Comment: Start with $\frac1{z^2}= \sum_{k=1}^K B_{k-1}(\frac1{z^k}-\frac1{(z+1)^k})+O(z^{-K-1})$,
$(\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)})' = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac1{(z+n)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\psi(x+i y)=\frac{i \pi }{2}+\log (y)+\frac{i(1-2x)}{2y}+\frac{6 (x-1)
   x+1}{12 y^2}+$$ $$\frac{i (x-1) x (2 x-1)}{6
   y^3}-\frac{30 x^4-60 x^3+30 x^2-1}{120 y^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^5}\right)$$
seems to be quite decent even for small values of $y$. Trying for $x=\pi$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
y & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
3 & 1.342042544+0.909681077 \, i & 1.385304688+0.846249307 \, i \\
 4 & 1.557580397+1.002964134 \, i & 1.566566745+0.985468467 \, i \\
 5 & 1.729238357+1.089871573 \, i & 1.731792660+1.083668377 \, i \\
 6 & 1.878793427+1.157957839 \, i & 1.879690031+1.155348063 \, i \\
 7 & 2.011554222+1.210697732 \, i & 2.011920434+1.209455057 \, i \\
 8 & 2.130545425+1.252167991 \, i & 2.130713040+1.251518287 \, i \\
 9 & 2.238060772+1.285412537 \, i & 2.238144592+1.285047147 \, i \\
 10 & 2.335927665+1.312561284 \, i & 2.335972655+1.312343426 \, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, is that a proven expansion (in which case do you have a reference or a method of proof?) or a numerical suitable approximation?

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus. I don't know. I (say a CAS) made it for you. You could be interested by equation 5.119 at https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11 . Look also http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1363-4.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the references, these are for $\Gamma$. My question was more about: how did you get it? Did you use $\Gamma$'s Stirling formula, or anything else?

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus Try that : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BPolyGamma%5B0%2Cx%2BI+y%5D%2C%7By%2CInfinity%2C2%7D%5D

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating [the known asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E8) of $\log\Gamma(z+h)$ with respect to $z$ gives
$$
\psi (z + h) \sim \log z + \frac{{2h - 1}}{{2z}} - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k B_k (h)}}{k}\frac{1}{{z^k }}} ,
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$, with any fixed $h\in \mathbb C$. Here $B_k$ denotes the $k$th Bernoulli polynomial. Taking $h=x_0\in \mathbb R$ and $z=\pm\mathrm{i}y$ with $y>0$, we obtain
$$
\psi (x_0  \pm {\rm i}y) \sim \log y \pm \frac{\pi }{2}{\rm i} \mp \frac{{2x_0  - 1}}{{2y}}{\rm i} - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{( \pm {\rm i})^k B_k (x_0 )}}{k}\frac{1}{{y^k }}} 
$$
as $y\to+\infty$.